# createbottomtabnavigator not visible on all screens

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

hi guys I am working with createbottomtabnavigator in react native, however, the bottom tab is not visible on all screens, I am searched the internet, but I cannot seem to find any solution. I  want to be able to display the bottom tab on all screens except the login, signup, welcome, forgot screens. and also, the transition from one screen to another is lagging. Any suggestion would be appreciated. code is presented below

```
      import React from 'react';
      import { Image } from 'react-native';
      import { createAppContainer, createStackNavigator,
        createBottomTabNavigator, createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
      import Payment from '../screens/containers/Payment';
      import Notification from './screens/containers/Notification';
      import Predictions from './screens/containers/Predictions';
      import Orion from './screens/containers/Orion';
      import Results from './screens/containers/Results';
      import Welcome from '../screens/Welcome';
      import Login from '../screens/Login';
      import SignUp from '../screens/SignUp';
      import Forgot from '../screens/Forgot';
      import Explore from '../screens/Explore';
      import Browse from '../screens/Browse';
      import Product from '../screens/Product';
      import Settings from '../screens/Settings';
      import Map from '../screens/Map';
      import { Account, Edits, Imports, Exports,
        International, Local, Ozone, } from '../screens/containers/Profile/Screens/Account';



      const LoggedInNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
        Orion,
        Payment,
        Results,
        Notification,
        Predictions,
      }, {
        initialRouteName: 'Results',
        tabBarOptions: {
          tabBarVisible: true,
          animationEnabled: true,
          showLabel: false,
          marginBottom: 5,
          activeTintColor: 'red',
          inactiveTintColor: '#grey',
          style: {
            backgroundColor: '#FAFAFA',
          }
        },
      }
      );


      const screens = createStackNavigator({
        Import,
        Export,
        Ozone,
        Local,
        International,
        Edit,
        Forgot,
        Account,
        Welcome,
        Login,
        SignUp,
        Explore,
        Browse,
        Product,
        Settings,
      }, {
        navigationOptions: {
          tabBarVisible: true,
          animationEnabled: true,
        },
      });

      const switcher = createSwitchNavigator(
        {
          Tab: LoggedInNavigator,
          Login: screens,
        },
        {
          initialRouteName: 'Tab'
        }
      );


      //export default createAppContainer(LoggedInNavigator, screens);

      export default createAppContainer(switcher);
```

Answer (score 1):

Those components that you want to make bottom navigation visible to them must be configured within `createBottomTabNavigator`.
You can use nested navigation like this :

```
const screens = createStackNavigator({
        Import,
        Export,
        Ozone,
        Local,
        International,
        Edit,
        Forgot,
        Account,
        Welcome,
        Login,
        SignUp,
        Explore,
        Browse,
        Product,
        Settings,
      }, {
        navigationOptions: {
          tabBarVisible: true,
          animationEnabled: true,
        },
      });

const LoggedInNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
        Orion,
        Payment,
        Results,
        Notification,
        Predictions,
        Screens: screens // <== Nested stackNavigator inside bottomTabNavigator
      }, {
        initialRouteName: 'Results',
        tabBarOptions: {
          tabBarVisible: true,
          animationEnabled: true,
          showLabel: false,
          marginBottom: 5,
          activeTintColor: 'red',
          inactiveTintColor: '#grey',
          style: {
            backgroundColor: '#FAFAFA',
          }
        },
      }
      );
```

It depends on what components should be in each tab! 
You can create `stackNavigator` for each tabs and put them inside `createBottomNavigator`.